# How to install Megasync client in Arch-based Antergos Linux

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, antergos

The client seems absent in the repositories in the latest Antergos Linux.

Although [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/09/download-megasync-for-linux-desktops.html) it is said that it is supposed to be accessible via AUR.

Answer (score 1):

The discussion under [the AUR page](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/megasync/) seemed confusing to me but what worked in the end was the Comment by sarri-on, saying that megasync 2.0.0-2 has some problem with the checksums. The solution is:

- Download only the PKGBUILD file

  ```
  yaourt -G megasync
  ```
- Install ignoring integrity checksum

  ```
  cd /tmp/yaourt-tmp-username/megasync
  ```

But in my case the path was

```
~/megasync
```

So, I opened there a terminal and ran:

```
makepkg -i --skipinteg PKGBUILD
```

Which got me this:

> ```
> ==> Missing dependencies:  
> -> c-ares  
> -> crypto++
> ```

So:

```
sudo pacman c-ares
```

and

```
sudo pacman -S crypto++
```

And then again:

```
makepkg -i --skipinteg PKGBUILD
```

Comment: `makepkg` can install dependencies itself, just pass it the `-s` or `--syncdeps` argument. Your first pacman command doesn't look right, either, it's missing the `-S` or `--sync` operation and both pacman commands should also have the `--asdep` flag.

Answer (score 0):

MEGA is now offering a megasync package for ArchLinux. You can download it from: https://mega.nz/#sync. It will also configure their official repo, so that updates will work and you can install nautilus extension.